# print a Node object in java

Tags: java

I am trying to debug on java code.

since there is no ide , I need to log every statement and see the result. one of the code line is as below, which is inside a for loop

```
Node node1 = nodelist1.item(j)
```

I want to see ,what is inside node1.

I tried like `(new StringBuilder()).append(node1)`
but this didn't even compile.

please suggest me a way so that I can make this as a string.

Comment: Define a `toString` method on your `Node` class.

Comment: I did not define this Node class actually this is some standard class I believe.

Comment: Then it has a `toString`, like every Java object. Call that.

Comment: `System.out.println(node1);`

Comment: Hi Lashane, we don't use IDE in my project, we need to log this by calling some other method. we test this in environment - this is a java stored procedure loaded in oracle ebs R12.2.6, but now I am going to try the solution provided by aryamccarthy.

Comment: do you know what IDE is?

Comment: @aryamccarthy - I tried to print node1 and node1.toString() , but the output is oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLText@49ef89eb in both cases.

Comment: And now we know *which* `Node`. Try the `getNodeValue()` instance method: `node1.getNodeValue()`.

Comment: @aryamccarthy. now am getting empty spaces printed. but when I check if its null or not - returns 'not null' - Weird :(

Comment: @aryamccarthy .. I will accept the answer you provided . please post it in the answer section

Comment: Posted it, as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your node is a standard library XML node. It doesn't have a helpful `toString`.

You definitely need something that gives you a string. Depending on what content you want to see, you can use either

```
node1.getNodeValue()
```

or

```
node1.getText()
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll find all the info about that node [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28391/oracle/xml/parser/v2/XMLNode.html).

You can verify its type by checking `instaneof XMLNode`